# If $H\subseteq G$, $K\subseteq H$ and $K\unlhd G$, with $G$ a group and $H, K$ its subgroups, does this imply $K\unlhd H$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $H\subseteq G$, $K \subseteq H$ and $K \unlhd G$, with $G$ a group and $H, K$ two its subgroups, does this imply $K \unlhd H$?

It seems to me obvious, but I was searching for a proof of it.

EDIT: I'll enrich the question giving a context to it, since some comments are asking for it.

The above sentence comes from Herstein's "Abstract Algebra (Third Edition)" textbook, during the proof of the correspondence theorem, page 86 [here](https://ict.iitk.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/CS203-Mathematics-for-Computer-Science-III-Herstein-3thEditon.pdf).

> Since $K \unlhd G$ and $K \subseteq H$, it follows $K \unlhd H$

I started from normality: $g^{-1}Kg \subseteq K$ , without using cosets. Then I tried to add to It H Is a subset, but I wasn't able to go on, since I don't want to use cosets here.
So I could say:

$g^{-1}Kg \subseteq K, g\in G$

but $H \subset G$

so $h^{-1}Kh \subseteq K, h \in H\implies K \lhd H$

Is that enough?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138678/discussion-on-question-by-riccardoventrella-if-h-subseteq-g-k-subseteq-h-an).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is enough.

---

Alternatively . . .

Since $K\unlhd G$, by definition of normality, we have for all $g\in G$ that

$$gK=Kg.$$

But $H\le G$ and so, letting $g=h\in H$,

$$hK=Kh.$$

Also $K\le H$. Therefore, again by definition of normality, we have $K\unlhd H$.

Comment: $K$ Is a subgroup of $H$ as given statement at the beginning

Comment: Not exactly, @riccardoventrella. It says it's a subset and it says it's a group. This does not *strictly* say it is a subgroup.

Comment: I've fixed that, even if It was obvious by the $\subseteq$

Comment: Fine, @riccardoventrella. Your attempt holds then. I have edited my answer. However, in future, if you ask one question but mean another, keep the old one and then ask your intended question separately.

Comment: OK @Shaun , thanks